# Looking for Polars for Liebeck LI74 with a Cl of 4.8!

Tags: aircraft-design

Looking for Polars for Liebeck LI74 with a Cl of 4.8!!

Does anyone have any info on this foil?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. lol.  I actually want to build a low span biplane ultralight. Trying to model it in XFLR5 first. Copying a bit of the Zenith 701 with a cl of 3. Want short takeoff and landing, as in 50 feet or less. Re 300-600k.  It has a slat and a junkers flap, so sort of a multi element foil already.

Comment: Can someone answer with: there aren't any polars available so I can check off the answer, or is there a way to delete this question?

Comment: @Fred there is no need to delete it, it can remain open. It is hard to prove a negative, but maybe someone will provide a polar for this airfoil in the future.